# how to check two conditions in while loop ruby

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I am trying to develop a program to show heroscope i have given 5 zodiac sign with methods with conditional statement, and in method i am asking one more question like choose between and when i am giving 2 conditions in if else it working fine,

but now i want to add that if user enter wrong condition rather than 1 , 2 it should prompt you entered wrong no please choose again and again option should be displayed, i am thinking to give two condition in while loop and then if else condition one condition in while is working fine but i want to check two conditions please help me thanks in advance.

def sagittarius

```
puts "Now choose between: 1. rainbow and 2. meteors again"
  color = gets.chomp.to_i
while (color !=1 ||color !=2)
    puts "wrong no pls renter no"
    
 color = gets.chomp.to_i
end
if color == 1   
    puts "The connection with your soul mate seems to be fading away due to work pressures"
elsif color == 2
    puts "Today you will begin to realize how some moderate changes in your lifestyle can help you lead a healthier and happier life"   
else
    "choose again!!"
end
```

end

Comment: Your condition can never be false.

Comment: Consider writing `color = loop do; puts "Choose between: 1. rainbow and 2. meteors"; color = gets.chomp; break color if ["1", "2"].include?(color); puts "wrong no pls renter no"; sleep(2); end`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `color` was `1` then `(color !=1 ||color !=2)` the second part of the condition would be true and because of the `||` the whole condition would be `true`.

Instead, you need to check

```
while (color != 1 && color != 2)
```

because you want the condition to be `true` when color is not `1` *and* when it is not `2`. Which can be transformed into the following that might be easier to understand.

```
while !(color == 1 || color == 2)
```

Another way to write is would be using [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
while ![1, 2].include?(color)
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting an answer when it was helpful and accepting an answer when it solved your problem. This is a way to say thank you and to indicate to others the answer fixes the issue.